# How can I search multiple lines that contain different values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My long term goal is to be able to read a file, and look for multiple lines that contain a certain Id and extract data from those lines. Right now I am trying to find certain lines that contain those certain Ids and print those lines so I know that I have the right data.

Every line starts with {"id": "101", and it has a different ID number, but it also has a long record number and in any record number could contain some ID numbers so I am searching for " "id#" " like below.

```
handle = open('info.txt')
for line in handle:
    if not '"101"' in line:
        continue
    print(line)
```

The code above work, but if I want to pull multiple values like, 101 110 170 230 I wanted to try something like this.

```
handle = open('info.txt')
for line in handle:
    if not '"101"' '"110"' '"170"' '"130"' in line:
        continue
    print(line)
```

but that doesn't seem to work. I also tried creating a list, but seems like I can use list.

Comment: Please show a small example (3 or 4 lines is enough) of the data in info.txt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find any ID then use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any).

```
ids = ['101', '110', '120', '170', '130']

with open('info.txt') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        if not any(id_ in line for id_ in ids):
            continue
        print(line)
```

I used the `with` statement because it will close the file after the `with`block - something you forgot. And I named the variable `id_` and not `id` because I didn't want to overwrite the builtin [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id).

Since you said that "Every line starts with `{"id": "101"`, and it has a different ID number," you might not just want to check if the id is somewhere in the line but if the line starts with this sequence.

```
with open('info.txt') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        if not any(line.startswith(f'{{"id": "{id_}"') for id_ in ids):
            continue
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want something like

```
valid_values = ['"101"', '"110"', '"170"', '"130"']

for line in handle:
    if not any(value in line for value in valid_values):
        continue
    print(line)
```

First, you define the valid values in an easy to access list. Then, the any function checks each of those values in turn for each line

Answer (score 0):

You can use [any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any), i.e.:

```
m = ["101", "110", "170", "130"]

with open("info.txt") as f:
  for l in f:
    if not any(v in l for v in m):
      continue
    print(l)
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/4feb1b397a)

Comment: Just a small hint: There's no need to build a list in `any([v in l for v in m])`. With this approach you will have to build the whole list before checking with `any`. Use a generator with `any(v in l for v in m)`. This will stop the evaluation if an item is found.

Comment: You're right, it's list comprehension habit, corrected now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
if not '"101"' '"110"' '"170"' '"130"' in line:
```

Separating strings with spaces like that in Python is a form of concatenation that evaluates to something like:

```
if not '"101""110""170""130"' in line:
```

Which, as you might imagine will never be found.  What you need instead is something like a helper function that will iterate over your id list:

```
id_list =  ['"101"', '"110"', '"170"', '"130"']

def id_in_line(line):
   for id in id_list:
      if id in line:
          return True
    return False

handle = open('info.txt')
for line in handle:
    if not id_in_line(line):
        continue
    print(line)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library to do just that! the `json.loads()` function should do the job! and for looking trough the data you should be able to do something like this:

```py
for id in data.keys():
    if id == '123455789':
        #do something
```

Comment: How do you know the file is in JSON format?

Comment: just judging from this: "Every line starts with {"id": "101",", it seems just to be a regular dict? *sorry if im getting something wrong here*

Comment: Might be. Might not. If it's really JSON then your approach is fine.